# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: airflow

Having that error in `ariflow's scheduler`:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta'
> and 'float'

I am not able to find from where is it comming from. Any idea?

Full error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py",
> line 1275, in _execute
> self._run_scheduler_loop()   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py",
> line 1377, in _run_scheduler_loop
> num_queued_tis = self._do_scheduling(session)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py",
> line 1515, in _do_scheduling
> self._schedule_dag_run(dag_run, active_runs_by_dag_id.get(dag_run.dag_id, set()), session)   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py",
> line 1677, in _schedule_dag_run
> schedulable_tis, callback_to_run = dag_run.update_state(session=session, execute_callbacks=False)   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py",
> line 62, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagrun.py",
> line 405, in update_state
> info = self.task_instance_scheduling_decisions(session)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py",
> line 62, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagrun.py",
> line 499, in task_instance_scheduling_decisions
> schedulable_tis, changed_tis = self._get_ready_tis(scheduleable_tasks, finished_tasks, session)
> File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagrun.py",
> line 527, in _get_ready_tis
> session=session,   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py",
> line 62, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> line 813, in are_dependencies_met
> for dep_status in self.get_failed_dep_statuses(dep_context=dep_context,
> session=session):   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> line 834, in get_failed_dep_statuses
> for dep_status in dep.get_dep_statuses(self, session, dep_context):   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/ti_deps/deps/base_ti_dep.py",
> line 101, in get_dep_statuses
> yield from self._get_dep_statuses(ti, session, dep_context)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/ti_deps/deps/not_in_retry_period_dep.py",
> line 47, in _get_dep_statuses
> next_task_retry_date = ti.next_retry_datetime()   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> line 880, in next_retry_datetime
> delay = min(self.task.max_retry_delay, delay) TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float'
> [2023-08-18 09:56:20,249] {process_utils.py:95} INFO - Sending
> Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 237 [2023-08-18 09:56:20,502]
> {process_utils.py:61} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=237,
> status='terminated', exitcode=0, started='09:56:18') (237) terminated
> with exit code 0 [2023-08-18 09:56:20,503] {scheduler_job.py:1296}
> INFO - Exited execute loop

Comment: WHat version of Airflow is this? [A similar issue was fixed in 2.0.1](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13667)

Comment: @RNHTTR it's airflow 2.0 if not mistaken

Comment: Airflow 2.0.0 is ~3 years old at this point. I strongly recommend upgrading.

Comment: Upgrading to 2.6 solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been [solved in 2.0.1](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13667). I recommend upgrading Airflow to a more recent version, and keeping Airflow as up to date as possible to take advantage of bug fixes and new features.